# One Model multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am working on an application relying on mvvm. To simplify my question only a rough description what i want to do.

I have an application with one model, a mainwindow and two usercontrols each with a viewmodel. When i start my application on my mainwindow usercontrol one appears with two textboxes so i can enter some data. on my mainwindow there is also a button. With this button i can switch from usercontrol one to usercontrol two. On usercontrol two i want to display the datas i entered in usercontrol one.

- To switch from usercontrol one to usercontrol two is no problem.
- The problem is to show the entered datas from usercontrol one. How can i arrange this?

I'm not using any frameworks.

Comment: Post your code.  [mcve]

Comment: You could use commands and command parameters? Or pass the VM state into the command impl's.

Comment: ie You need to pass data from one VM to other VM right? Simply use **RelayCommands** or **Events**

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single model and a single view.

The view would contain both controls and when one is visible the other one isn't.

The viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

If both user controls are bound to properties on the viewmodel and those properties notify property changes it will all work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but imagine you have a usercontrol to enter let's say 20 datas, and then you have a different usercontrol where you want to display a summary and you don't want to do this on the same view.

Comment: As long as both usercontrols have a mutual parent, e.g. Main Window, you can share data through the parents viewmodel.

Comment: @Seeker63 If you don't want to put everything into MainWindow's VM, you can also create a repository kind of class using singleton pattern. Have the repository implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and have interested ViewModels subscribe to the relevant property's PropertyChanged event.